# Arduino LCD shows only black boxes

Tags: lcd, wires

I've hooked up my Arduino on [this](http://arduino.cc/documents/datasheets/LCD-WH1602B-TMI.pdf) LCD, and after running the following code, all I see is a row with black boxes and another one empty.

```
//LiquidCrystal d(RS, E, D4, D5, D6, D7);
LiquidCrystal lcd(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

void setup() {                
     lcd.begin(16, 2);
     lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {
     lcd.print("hello, world!");       
}
```

Wiring:
[image: table showing wiring between arduino and lcd]

(The UTP cable is used just for the data lines :-)

Actual wiring photos: (sorry for the total klutz in the wiring, I had limited solid-core wires so I had to use these scrap ones)

[image: wiring]
[image: wiring]
[image: wiring]

Comment: CAT 5 solid core is notorious for making poor connection in a breadboard. Have you tried a continuity check between the output pin of the MCU and the LCD input pin for each? That is, checking it without touching the wire in question.

Comment: I think your contrast resistor may be too high. Do you have a 10k pot so you can adjust it? Do you also have a schematic that you're following? Can you post this up

Comment: I'l try connecting with non-CAT5e wires and report back

Comment: @Samuel I just tried with normal solid-core wires and still nothing, so I believe wire problems are ruled out.

Comment: @BigChris I'm afraid i don't actually have breadboard space for a potentiometer ):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the R/W pin on the LCD was left floating, after I connected it to GND, I started working :)